# Did any particular speech give rise to "cultural enrichment" becoming a anti-immigration catchphrase?

Tags: united-states, immigration

The phrase "Cultural enrichment" is being used sarcastically by many people opposed to certain types of immigration.

Urban Dictionary has two [entries](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cultural%20enrichment) that are sarcastic about the phrase:

> Satirical term for invasion or general violence caused by pople of
>   different culture.
>
> Prepare for some cultural enrichment, Gondor!
>
> or
>
> Damn, this guy just got culturally enriched.

and

> attempting to convert one's culture to your own.
>
> you heard about Germany letting in syrian refugees? Yes lets pretend
>   to be syrian and give them a taste of cultural enrichment!

Did any particular speech or statement give rise to "cultural enrichment" being used sarcastically so often?

Comment: Is Urban Dictionary really a reliable primary source? :)

Comment: I seriously doubt that this came out of a specific speech, as opposed to general "I am gonna make fun of leftist views and semantically wrong language".

Comment: @user4012 I wouldn't call it a secondary or tertiary source, and I wouldn't categorise a primary source as reliable or unreliable. And I'd rather cite Urban Dictionary than the twitter account prisonplanet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase was "cultural enricher" used already in Germany during WW1 ("Kulturträger") and was then ironically referring to French troops that came from the colonies.

[image: Französische Kulturträger: In den Kämpfen bei Verdun gefangener Senegalneger (‘Mumbo’, der Schönste von allen). Source: Illustrirte Zeitung Nr 3826 (Kriegsnummer 117) page 558 (J J Weber, Leipzig, October 1916)]

With the nazis the word started to be used in the way we see today. For instance in Mein Kampf Adfrolf Hitler wrote:

> Vor allem aber die deutsche Kultur ist, wie schon ihr Name sagt, eine deutsche und keine jüdische… Denn wie mußte man uns dankbar sein, **daß wir diese herrlichen Kulturträger freigeben und der anderen Welt zur Verfügung stellen**. Sie kann nach ihren eigenen Erklärungen nicht einen Grund zur Entschuldigung anführen, weshalb sie diesen wertvollsten Menschen die Aufnahme in ihren Ländern verweigert.

Here Hitler used the phrase "these magnificent culture enrichers" as an ironic term for Jews.

From there it spread to nazi propaganda in general and from there on to the neo-nazis after the war and from there on to the wider far right.([Dog whistling far-right code words: the case of ‘culture enricher' on the Swedish web](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/1369118X.2021.1889639))

Comment: This sounds reminiscent of [Lying press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lying_press)

Comment: For what it's worth, _träger_ does not literally mean "enricher"; first, it is plural, and second, it means "bearers" or "carriers," so a literal translation of _Kulturträger_ is "culture bearers."  I don't know where the shift occurred, but this difference certainly does not seem to imply a lack of connection between "cultural enrichment" and _Kulturträger._  One may similarly see a connection between "fake news" and _Lügenpresse._